# Powershell - Remapping shortcuts based on new drive letters

Tags: powershell, drive-mapping

We're currently in the process of remapping all network drives to a new fileserver and with this, took it upon ourselves to map all of the fileshares to a uniform system (ex. everyone's public drive is Z:). With this, several people have shortcuts on their desktop. Is there a way in powershell we'd be able to change over the filepath of .lnk's from \oldfs to \newfs.

`
$folder = "C:\Users$env:USERNAME\OneDrive\Desktop"

```
$from = "[A-Z]:"

$to = \\newfs

Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Filter *.lnk -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

    $WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

    $ShortcutFile = "$($_.FullName)"

    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)



    if ($Drive.RemotePath -like "*oldfs*") {

        $Shortcut.TargetPath = $Shortcut.TargetPath -replace $from, $to

        $Shortcut.Save()

    }

}
```

`
This is what we've come up with so far.
Any help would be appreciated :)

I've ran through a couple different scripts.

```
function Resolve-ShortcutTarget {
    param (
        [string]$shortcutPath
    )

    $shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut($shortcutPath)
    $targetPath = $shortcut.TargetPath

    if ($targetPath -match '^([a-z]):') {
        $driveLetter = $matches[1]
        $networkDrive = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object { $_.DeviceID -eq     "$($driveLetter):" }

        if ($networkDrive) {
            $networkPath = $networkDrive.ProviderName
            $targetPath = $targetPath -replace "^$($driveLetter):", $networkPath
        }
    }

    return $targetPath
}

$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$desktopPath = Join-Path $env:SystemDrive "Users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop"
$desktopItems = $shell.Namespace($desktopPath).Items()

$desktopInfoList = foreach ($item in $desktopItems) {
    if ($item.IsFileSystem) {
        $targetPath = $item.Path

        if ($item.Type -eq 'Shortcut') {
            try {
                $targetPath = Resolve-ShortcutTarget -shortcutPath $targetPath
            } catch {
                Write-Warning "Failed to resolve target path for shortcut: $targetPath"
                $targetPath = $null
            }
        }

        $computerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

        try {
            $owner = (Get-Acl -LiteralPath $targetPath -ErrorAction Stop).Owner
        } catch {
            Write-Warning "Failed to get ACL for: $targetPath"
            $owner = $null
        }

        $directoryName = $null
        if ($targetPath) {
            try {
                $directoryName = (Get-Item $targetPath -ErrorAction Stop).DirectoryName
            } catch {
                Write-Warning "Failed to get directory information for: $targetPath"
            }
        }

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Name"          = $item.Name
            "DirectoryName" = $directoryName
            "Directory"     = $targetPath
            "Computer"      = $computerName
            "Owner"         = $owner
            "Type"          = $item.Type
            "Target"        = $targetPath
        }
    }
}

# Export the information to a CSV file
$desktopInfoList | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop\desktop_items.csv" -     NoTypeInformation
```

`

This did work in terms of locating & listing all of the shortcuts on one's desktop. I did run into null value issues though.